# how to combine several mysql scripts (drop / create) to execute them at once?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Please explain how to combine two scripts e.g. 
 **create procedure1** & **create procedure2** in order to execute them at once.

I have created a several stored procedures and I wish to give them to other colleagues to execute them but I can't find a way how to compose them to execute them all at once.

Comment: What OS are you and your colleagues using?

Comment: We are using MacOS with phpmyadmin

Comment: Then my answer will work from the MacOS terminal command line (no need to involve phpmyadmin)

Comment: @Bohemian  unfortunately, it's necessary to work through phpmyadmin

Comment: My recommendation would be to dispense with "procedure": There is absolutely no *real* reason that you "must use phpmyadmin". Don't use it and get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a *nix OS, do this:

```
mysql mydbname < `cat script1 script2`
```